# Conditionally hide or show Aspx Menu Control Item

Tags: c#, asp.net, menuitem

How do I hide or show a menu item based on a backend condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove that particular menu item as follows:

```
MenuItem mnuItem = mnu.FindItem(""); // Find particular item
mnu.Items.Remove(mnuItem);
```

Answer (score 1):

Found a few links. Basically it looks like this will do the trick...

```
MyMenu.Items(1).Visible = False
```

- http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=401836
- http://forums.asp.net/t/1451884.aspx/1
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178429(VS.80).aspx

Any of those should give you what you need to hide menu items.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to remove it from the Menu:

```
protected void MyMenu_MenuItemDataBound(object sender, MenuEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.Text == "Menu Item To Remove")
        {
             MyMenu.Items.Remove(e.Item);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Public Boolean Condition
{
   get { ... }
}


<asp:Menu ID="..." runat="server">
  <Items>
    <asp:MenuItem Text="..." Value="..." Visible="<%# this.Condition %>" />

    .....
  </Items>
</asp:Menu>
```